# Activate a search on another website

Tags: html, forms

I am trying to embed the search forms of two other sites into my own site. Here is my site, the forms are at the bottom: http://dsa.dartmouth.edu/.

The DGD search works fine - the user gets directed to the search results page - but the Course Picker one doesn't - the user just gets redirected to a blank search page.

This is my form code:

```
<form action="http://coursetown.hacktown.cs.dartmouth.edu/search" method="post" class="appSearch">
       <input id="search" name="query[title]" placeholder="course title(s)" type="text" role="textbox">
       <input type='submit' name='commit' type="submit" value='Search' />
</form>
```

Is there a way to make it so that the user gets directed to coursetown's search results page when they click search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search form on http://coursetown.hacktown.cs.dartmouth.edu/search submits by AJAX so there is no search URL to hit. Furthermore, it seems to use a hidden "authenticity_token" field, which is probably generated server-side on load so you probably need to find out if they have an API you can use for this.

If you can edit that page directly to trigger the search by JavaScript based on URL parameters that would be an option too, not sure what level of control you have over the search page.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Didn't know for sure if there wasn't another way